# TensorFlow OOM when looping over multiple experiments

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, tensorflow2.0

Using **TensorFlow 2.4.1**, I'm running multiple experiments or **grid-search** successively:

1. creating models
2. training on them
3. and then losing their reference

After a certain amount of iterations, I run into **OOM errors** and no successive experiment manage to allocated the required memory to run.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor
```

- The models are all the same with a grid search on the learning rate. The tensor for which TensorFlow failed to allocate memory has been successfully allocated in the previous experiment iterations
- I tried running each experiment in a `multiprocessing.Process` like recommended on https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36465#issuecomment-582749350
- I tried calling `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` at the begining of each process as recommended on https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session, without success.
- I tried setting memory growth with `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth` but, using `nvidia-smi`, the allocated memory stays **identical** between runs that succeed and runs that fail with OOM (43474/45556 MB)

I'm running out of idea on how to prevent this out-of-memory error with TensorFlow.

Is there any recommendations on how to run multiple successive experiments with TensorFlow?

Comment: Please share some reproducible code.

Comment: not easy because code-base is huge, and the problem takes time to occur… I'm going to try. Thanks.